# Subtle mistake of changing label value of an array

Tags: dictionary

### Problem

I am trying to map the original label 769, 770, 771 and 772 to 0, 1, 2 and 3. However, when I am trying to do this with dictionary, the `y_test` in the following does not change.

Note the `dataDict` is preprocessed dictionary where key "y_test" and "y_train_valid" both correspond to 1D array of type `int32`.

```
mappingDict = {769: 0, 770: 1, 771: 2, 772: 3}
y_train = dataDict["y_train_valid"].copy()
y_test = dataDict["y_test"].copy()
for label, newLabel in mappingDict.items():
    y_train[y_train == label] = newLabel
    y_test[y_test == label] == newLabel
```

### MWE

To reproduce what happened, you could try the following and will end up getting 
[image]

```
y_train = np.array([771, 772, 769, 769, 769, 769, 771, 770, 772, 772], dtype="int32")
y_test = np.array([770, 769, 771, 772, 772, 771, 771, 772, 772, 769], dtype="int32")
mappingDict = {769: 0, 770: 1, 771: 2, 772: 3}

for label, newLabel in mappingDict.items():
    y_train[y_train == label] = newLabel
    y_test[y_test == label] == newLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid mistake, but took me 30 minutes.

I somehow added an additional `=` in `y_test[y_test == label] = newLabel` and this results in `y_test[y_test == label] == newLabel`